# create a pie chart with passing some values

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, pie-chart

I am making an application in iPad which is based on creating pie chart after detecting marks like 280 out of 400. I have to create pie chart based on that marks which shows total marks and also obtain marks.

If someone has an idea about it please let me know.

Comment: I would really suggest you to do some research before asking questions here. Giving "pie chart draw ios" query on google already answers your question.

Comment: @FahriAzimov I researched before asking question..

Comment: https://www.google.com/#q=pie+chart+draw+ios&hl=en&tbo=u&tbm=dsc&sa=X&psj=1&ei=1Y-sUMXAJqjtiQLplIDYDA&ved=0CEcQmAcwAQ&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=5e8c8770aa1df990&bpcl=38897761&biw=1395&bih=783, Also check coreplot.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I forgot to mention how to get to the google, Thanks @ACB! Cheers! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [CorePlot's](https://code.google.com/p/core-plot/) [CPTPieChart](http://core-plot.googlecode.com/hg/documentation/html/iOS/interface_c_p_t_pie_chart.html) class

Answer (score 1):

Refer [MIMChart-Library](https://github.com/ReetuRaj/MIMChart-Library) which has differnt styles in each category.